# How can I open or play Aladdin's soundtrack (JAM audio format)?

Tags: technical-issues, dos, disneys-aladdin-1993

I have the DOS version of Disney and Virgin Interactive Entertainment's game [Aladdin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disney%27s_Aladdin_(Virgin_Games_video_game)). The game soundtrack seems to be stored as `.JAM` files according to [this page](http://jam.fileextensionguide.com) (see the *type 3 description*) but no details are provided.

Does anyone know how these files can preferably be played back unaltered or converted to a more common format? (By the latter I do not mean recording or capturing the audio while the game is running.)

Comment: Sorry Dan, but this site is about playing games, not playing obscure-format audio files. That the files came from a game originally doesn't really change that.

Comment: @BillyMailman: I thought my question might fall under the "Game-specific hardware and utilities" category (specifically the latter)? Anyway, if the query is off-topic kindly delete or close it since I can't do so.

Comment: Can you find any sample files online that we can experiment with? I'd avoid uploading one of yours unless you can ensure it won't be a copyright issue.

Comment: I have a hunch your JAM format is actually an archive format the game happens to store data in. 

Apparently this tool by Watto advertises itself as an extractor of a certain "JAM" format. It might not be the same format, but it might be related, since the 90's tech was a wild ride of proprietary software. 

Here's Watto's specification sheet for the format: http://www.watto.org/specs.html?specs=Archive_JAM_LJAM

Comment: https://fileinfo.com/extension/jam "JAM files can be converted to .WAV files using the Jam2Wav program." - "JAM files can be played back in Pyva.net JAM using instrument voices from a software synthesizer."

Comment: The tool by Watto had three plugins to attempt to open a `.JAM` file, but none worked. Some other pages out there seem to suggest that this audio format is an `.AMF` file representing *Otto Chrons' Digital Sound and Music Interface* / *Asylum Music Format*, but after some digging and inspecting, the `.JAM` file doesn't seem to be in the same format as the `.AMF` included with the game. http://www.vgmpf.com/Wiki/index.php?title=AMF